# How to make a radio button able to get unchecked?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I got a radio button in a radio group. It is dynamically created, so I haven't got the reference to the radio group the button is in. I would like to make it able for the app user to uncheck a radiobutton by again clicking on it. I tried a view things but couldn't succeed.

How do I do this?

I tried the following code:

```
rButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((RadioButton) v).isChecked()) {
            ((RadioButton) v).setSelected(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Problem is, that this if-clause is always true also if you press the radiobutton for the first time. AND more important the setSelected(false) doesn't work.

Thank you for any advice.

**Edit:**
I mad this foolish mistake of using setSelected instead of setChecked.
So with setChecked I can uncheck the radioButton. But so it is never checked, not even the first time.

Comment: you would probably have to create a button to unselect it.

Comment: try in OnClick
 rButton.setChecked(false);

Comment: @ElMaravilla please see my edit

Comment: if you cheking isChecked you must setChecked, if you checking isSelected you must setSelected

Comment: If it appears an error when you click on the radio button then try this :
if(rButton.isChecked()){
rButton.setChecked(false);
}

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos like I wrote in my Edit, I already do this now.

Comment: If it appears an error when you click on the radio button then try this :
if(rButton.isChecked()){
rButton.setChecked(false);
}

Comment: @ElMaravilla There is no error. The problem is, that I can't check a radiobutton in the app now. Because everytime I check it it gets directly unchecked.

Comment: try my answer now please.

Comment: Don't use RadioButtons if you want CheckBoxes.

Comment: @KlingKlang I don't want Checkboxes, that's why I am using radio buttons ;-)

Comment: But you want them to behave like CheckBoxes. Only CheckBoxes have the ability to be deselected. That's why I posted my comment.

Comment: @KlingKlang No I don't. In general I want them to behave like radiobuttons: I want that all other radiobuttons get unchecked when one of the radiobuttons in the same radiogroup are checked. (Typical radiobutton behaviour) I also want them to look like radiobuttons. I just want the possibility to also uncheck them. (yes this is typically checkbox behaviour). 

But so it is a symbiosis of radiobuttons and checkboxes. I don't want to use checkboxes and let them look like radio buttons..that would be stupid.

Comment: The point is... why do you want RadioButtons to behave **unnaturally**? People expects RadioButtons to follow their standard, rigid behavior: "one of many". "None" is not contemplated.

Comment: @KlingKlang Why does it matter WHY I want this?

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't need to make sense to you. It is just that I want the app-user to choose between different options. But he should only be able to check one option (that's why radio button). But at the same time it shouldn't be mandatory.

Comment: RadioButtons **are** mandatory. CheckBoxes **aren't**. You choose. OR you can write your own custom View.